# multiple userControl instances in tabControl

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, tabcontrol, itemtemplate

I have a tabControl that is bound to an observable collection. 
In the headerTemplate, I would like to bind to a string property, and in the contentTemplate I have placed a user-control.

Here's the code for the MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>            
        <DataTemplate x:Key="contentTemplate">
                <local:UserControl1 />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pages}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource contentTemplate}"/>

</Grid>
```

And its code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }        
}

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PageViewModel> Pages { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.Pages = new ObservableCollection<PageViewModel>();
        this.Pages.Add(new PageViewModel("first"));
        this.Pages.Add(new PageViewModel("second"));
    }
}

public class PageViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PageViewModel(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

So the problem in this scenario (having specified an itemTemplate as well as a controlTemplate) is that I only get **one** instance for the user-control, where I want to have an instance for each item that is bound to.

Comment: _"I want to have an instance for each item"_ -- please clarify your need here. _Why_ do you specifically one a new instance for each item? Please be specific: provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, and explain precisely what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do. _(My apologies for chiming in late...I only ran across this question [answering a different one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33125188); this may or may not be the same issue I addressed in the other one, so I thought I'd ask for clarification)_.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="contentTemplate" x:Shared="False">
            <local:UserControl1/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource contentTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

> x:Shared="False"
>
> When set to false, modifies Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) resource retrieval behavior such that requests for a resource will create a new instance for each request, rather than sharing the same instance for all requests.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I tried setting it on the contentTemplate but no luck. (not even when its defined in a separate resourceDictionary). And I'm not even allowed to set it on the userControl...

Comment: Read this article by Josh Smith (http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/my-mvvm-article-in-msdn-magazine/) In this article he host multiple views (usercontrols) in a tabcontrol...

Comment: Also look at this article (http://www.dev102.com/2009/03/02/tidy-up-your-xaml-and-code-behind-use-usercontrols-inside-templates/) I found this morning

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but in that example of Josh there's still only one instance created for the multiple views in the tabControl :s

Answer (score -1):

You need to override the `Equals()` Method of your `PageViewModel` class.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (!(obj is PageViewModel)) return false;

    return (obj as PageViewModel).Name == this.Name;
}
```

Something like this should work.

Now it is looking for the same property of the value Name. Otherwise you could also add a ID Property which is unique.